# Trying to block YouTube

Tags: iptables, youtube, https

I've tried two different commands in IPTables to block YouTube.  They briefly work, but then, hours later, or the next day, I test it again, only to find that it comes through when I DON'T want it to.  Does anyone know of a good solution to this?

Comment: Are you doing this on your local machine? Or in a company network?

Comment: Did you try this: open gksu gedit /etc/hosts and adding 0.0.0.1 www.youtube.com ?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're up against YouTube which is *huge* and has servers all over the planet and they use them very efficiently to stream Terabytes of data!!!

If you *really* want to do this: don't remove *any* YouTube address from your IPtables; just keep adding them and to start, just go  [here](http://networktools.nl/asinfo/youtube.com) for a list of YouTube IP addresses and add those all in.  Check it weekly as they keep adding servers...

**Fair warning:** Some day, when you finally nailed down all of the YouTube servers, someone will show up at your desk and tell you: "Look, there's this educational video on how to install my printer/teach me math/... and I really need it!" and then you're going to pull out all of your hair and remove the blocks you've so painstakingly put in.  (Your mileage may vary, though)

**Edit:** Additionally there might be circumstances where you actually block other Google services if you block huge ranges of YouTube IP addresses in *IPtables* or any other IP based filtering.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)  *And please, click it **before** you have a heart-attack after pulling out all of your hair.*  ;-)

Comment: Need to mention that i have also seen circumstances where some other Google services were blocked due to trying to block Youtube by huge IP ranges.

Comment: @heemayl Good one!  You might edit the answer and add it in!

Comment: can't you add a redirect in your `host` file? to a banned from this network page? I made something like that ages ago, to stop myself from going on YouTube. Didn't help.

Comment: @blade19899: on one machine: yes, on an entire network of 10, 100, 1000 machines: impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this maybe adding the line 
`0.0.0.0 youtube.com`
to `/etc/hosts`. If it still does not block Youtube try flushing the DNS cache by `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart`

I have verified this on `Linux-4.15`.

Comment: I don't think `0.0.0.0` is the right IP. Maybe a local IP if you don't want to use `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was encountering something like this while configuring iptables to block different IPs (not YouTube's). The problem I noticed was that when I turned off my my laptop, I would lose the configuration.

The best way to keep the configurations is saving it using the `iptables-save` command.